# addChildViewController giving NSException error?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to using this method so I could be doing this completely wrong so here is my code:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) ConverterViewController *converterViewController;
@property (nonatomic, weak) CalculatorViewController *calculatorViewController;
```

If I am understanding this code correctly, these are acting as references to Two different ViewControllers.

Then I have this in my viewDidAppear method:

```
[self addChildViewController:_converterViewController];
[_converterViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
[self.view addSubview:_converterViewController.view];
```

I am getting an NSException at the first line when I try and add it as a child view controller. So not knowing whether or not this should then call some methods in my ConverterViewController class I put some breakpoints within that class both the initWithNibName and viewDidLoad methods and I found that neither of these methods are being called, so Im not exactly sure what is wrong. Then again Im not really sure what could go wrong so any help is greatly appreciated.

This is all I get from the console:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: What's the exception name and reason? These are usually printed out to the console, but you can `po` them in the debugger.

Comment: @BergQuester Just ran the debugger and found that it is saying converterViewController is nil, how do i make it contain my View Controller? I have a view controller set up to be using this class.

Comment: that error is so vague. anyways... try `@property (nonatomic, strong)` instead of `@property (nonatomic, weak)`

Comment: I agree, try `strong` rather than `weak`. If that doesn't work, show us more code, including where you populate `calculatorViewController` and `converterViewController`.

Comment: post some more code related to `converterViewController`. including the alloc/init part (_you are doing that... right?_)

Comment: @BergQuester I have tried using strong, it doesn't change anything. also what do you mean by populate, I am really new to using child views so bear with me. Anyways do you mean the class that it is connected to?

Comment: @staticVoidMan I have shown all the code relating to converterViewController. I thought that the initWithNibName was the initialization of the child view, am I wrong? this is done in the ConverterViewController class.

Comment: yes, wrong. you need something like this `_converterViewController = [[ConverterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ConverterViewController" bundle:nil];` before you do `-addChildViewController:`

Comment: @JDOdle by populate I mean where do you set the values for those variables? Exactly what staticVoidMan is asking about. You must create the controller then assign it to the variable before you can use it.

Comment: @staticVoidMan got it thanks, I thought that initWithNibName was automatically run for me so thank you for clearing that up. add it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @JDOdle : I edited my previous answer. btw... in which class's `-viewDidAppear:` do you have this code running? (_just curious because you said it's done in `ConverterViewController` class. In which case you're adding `ConverterViewController` inside `ConverterViewController` and won't that result in a stack overflow?_)

Comment: @staticVoidMan no the viewDidAppear method is in my main view controller so that is working fine. however if your interested, it is not letting me add it as a subview of the main view controllers view. I was going to put this in a new question.

Comment: @JDOdle : so... what do you mean _"not letting me add it as a subview"_? ...What do you see and what do you expect?

Comment: @staticVoidMan I am actually just getting another error. the console is saying the same thing as last time. so i suppose that brings up another side question (don't need to answer it) as to why it is not giving me more specific errors. anyways that is the problem I am having.

Comment: @JDOdle : hm... ok (won't answer it) but there must be something else amiss that's totally unrelated to this and a new question would be a prudent decision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated Answer:**

`[self addChildViewController:_converterViewController];` does not create the `converterViewController`.
It simply takes the `converterViewController` object and adds it as a `childViewController` to `self`.

You will need to allocate memory and instantiate the object `converterViewController` before `-addChildViewController:` or else it's value will be `nil` and nothing will happen.

So... something this:

```
_converterViewController = [[ConverterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ConverterViewController"
                                                                     bundle:nil];

//now... adding it as childViewController should work
[self addChildViewController:_converterViewController];
[_converterViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
//optional: give it a frame explicitly so you may arrange more childViewControllers
//[_converterViewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)];
[self.view addSubview:_converterViewController.view];
```

Comment: Hmm strange I thought I fixed this, however the error occurs before this point so that doesn't fix my current problem. i will fix the code to reflect what it should be.