# How to add child view as a subview of a view controllers view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, addsubview

So far I have added a child view to my main view controller. however I want this child view to be a subview of my view controllers view so I tried to do it like this

```
[self.view addSubview:_converterViewController.view];
```

but this is giving me this error:

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   NSException

I know this is really vague but for some reason this is all I ever get. so what am I doing wrong? here is the code I have related to this task, and it is all located in my view controllers viewDidAppear method.

```
[self addChildViewController:_converterViewController];
[_converterViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
[self.view addSubview:_converterViewController.view];//this line produces the error
```

Thanks for the help.

Updated Error:

```
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB...
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [addChildViewController giving NSException error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23982965/addchildviewcontroller-giving-nsexception-error)

Comment: `libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException` is the last line of the error. scroll up the console a bit and you should get something like `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception ...`. This is what you need to quote here.

Comment: This explains a lot, I will add the error. Thanks

Comment: @JDOdle : do you see a `ConverterViewController.xib` in your project?

Comment: @staticVoidMan no, I am using Xcode 5 didn't they remove xib files in Xcode 5 or move them or something?

Comment: @JDOdle. well... they didn't remove xib (_but that's a different issue not of your concern right now_). Anyways, you need to simply `[[ConverterViewController alloc] init];` instead. Plus... delete the app from simulator or reset the simulator and then execute your app.

Comment: @staticVoidMan I am still getting an error after adding this code. it is giving me a warning saying that the result is unused.

Comment: @staticVoidMan Oh sorry i misunderstood what you meant. So now I am not getting an error but I am not able to see the added view. do i still need to load the view or something?

Comment: @JDOdle : well... the view is technically there and when you modify `converterViewController.view` programmatically, like adding a `UILabel` etc. or `[converterViewController.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];` then you'll see a difference. If you want the view you designed in the IB to appear (_while using storyboard_) then follow this [link](http://sandmoose.com/post/35714028270/storyboards-with-custom-container-view-controllers)

Comment: I have actually taken A look at this website and have tried to use this method, but the container view can not be sent to the back like other views can. is there another way I can get the content from the storyboard without using segues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my situation I had avoided having multiple views as part of the same view controller for UI design in IB however I reverted to this method after fixing my design issues. This eliminates all of the code needed for using child view controllers and renders my need for a solution to this problem void. I did this shortly before staticVoidMan posted his possible solution and I have no intention of going through the trouble of seeing if his solution works.

despite my decision to use other methods I greatly appreciate all the help I received on the matter.

Answer (score 2):

Here are steps that you need to do when adding childViewController

```
UIViewController *viewController = [UIViewController new];

[self addChildViewController:viewController];
[self.view addSubview:viewController.view];
[viewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

1 - Create Child View Controller
2 - Add is as a child
3 - Add it's view to the view hierarchy
4 - Notify childViewController that it has been added to the parent.

Comment: it's not a problem with adding child view controller. As you said it's problem of loading nib files. As you said - "Could not load NIB..." See if all your IBoutlets and IBActions are connected correctly

Answer (score 0):

For storyboard, do:

```
//instead of
//[[ConverterViewController alloc] init];
//do
//in my case, Storyboard name was "Main"
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
_converterViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ConverterViewController"];

//add as childViewController
[self addChildViewController:_converterViewController];
[_converterViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
//optional: modify parameters if needed
[_converterViewController.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[_converterViewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 64, 320, 100)];
[self.view addSubview:_converterViewController.view];
```

### Assumptions:

1. Name of storyboard is "`Main`" (*yours might be just "Storyboard"*)

   - [image: Project Targets]
2. Storyboard Identifier of `ConverterViewController` in storyboard is `ConverterViewController`

   - [image: Identity Inspector]